Extract historical and real time data from Yahoo Finance using R
I'm trying to extract Yahoo Finance data like this:
head(NQdata_one_minute)
# A tibble: 6 × 6
  timestamp         open   high    low  close volume
  <chr>            <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 5/19/2024 18:00 18634. 18647  18633  18644.    357
2 5/19/2024 18:01 18644  18645. 18638. 18640.    191
3 5/19/2024 18:02 18640  18644. 18640  18643      65
4 5/19/2024 18:03 18644. 18650  18643. 18650.     87
5 5/19/2024 18:04 18649. 18650  18647. 18650.    101
6 5/19/2024 18:05 18649. 18654. 18649. 18652.    147

for a certain period up to todays date with one minute timestamp. I subscribed to Yahoo for free and got my API key which I do not post here and I use the code below:
# Load required libraries
install.packages("httr")
install.packages("jsonlite")
install.packages("tibble")
install.packages("dplyr")
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

# Define your RapidAPI key
rapidapi_key <- "3820ecec24msheb4fc07be883ed8p106355jsn32ebbf92dfaa"

# Define the URL and payload for the POST request
url <- "https://yahoo-finance160.p.rapidapi.com/history"
payload <- "{\"stock\":\"TSLA\",\"period\":\"1mo\"}"

# Send the POST request
response <- VERB("POST", url, body = payload, add_headers(
  'x-rapidapi-key' = rapidapi_key,
  'x-rapidapi-host' = 'yahoo-finance160.p.rapidapi.com',
  'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
), encode = "json")

# Check if the request was successful
if (status_code(response) == 200) {
  # Parse the response as JSON
  data <- fromJSON(content(response, "text"), flatten = TRUE)
  
  # Extract the necessary fields and convert to a tibble
  historical_data <- data$prices
  
  stock_data <- tibble(
    timestamp = as.POSIXct(historical_data$formatted_date, format="%Y-%m-%d"),
    open = historical_data$open,
    high = historical_data$high,
    low = historical_data$low,
    close = historical_data$close,
    volume = historical_data$volume
  )
  
  # Print the tibble
  print(stock_data)
} else {
  stop("Failed to fetch data: ", status_code(response))
}

but I get an empty tibble
head(stock_data)
# A tibble: 0 × 1
# ℹ 1 variable: timestamp <dttm>

I also tried this but got data up to 2020 and with a data not a 1min timestamp.
